# Folder AccessControl - windows defender

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi

Is there a windows / .net API to check whether Folder Access Control is enabled? I am using the FileIOPermission (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission?view=netframework-4.8) to check for access (read and write) which succeeds however defender is still blocking attempts to write to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a key used in the registry to indicate whether Folder Access Control is enabled:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Exploit Guard\Controlled Folder Access`

`EnableControlledFolderAccess` Type: `DWORD`

0 = Off

1 = On

Comment: Thanks, that looks more promising however how do I tell if a particular folder (which is not a standard folder like My Documents etc) has access control enabled on it? I believe you can apply access control to any folder.

Comment: Maybe this could help:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Exploit Guard\Controlled Folder Access\ProtectedFolders`

Comment: Or you can get it with powershell:`Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ControlledFolderAccessProtectedFolders`
, `Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EnableControlledFolderAccess`